# Windows : make request on specific interface

Tags: windows, libcurl

I have 3 network interface plug in my pc (windows). I just wonder is there a easy way to make a http request from specific interface ?

I try curl but it seem not support windows.

Description here :  https://curl.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_INTERFACE.html

> libcurl does not support using network interface names for this option on Windows.

Here is my network details :

```
Ethernet adapter NETW 001:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::8a7:9368:bb58:1883%18
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.5.252
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.5.1

Ethernet adapter NETW 002:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::e4e0:bc83:3e56:8de0%13
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.78.252
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.78.1

Ethernet adapter NETW 003:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::f0e7:c451:335:8587%12
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.252
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not clear what stops you from using the specific interface by its IPv4 Address. The same manual:

> Pass a char * as parameter. This sets the interface name to use as outgoing network interface. The name can be an interface name, **an IP address**, or a host name.
> If the parameter starts with "host!" it is treated as either **an IP address** or a hostname.

```c
#if 1
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_INTERFACE, "192.168.78.252");
#else
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_INTERFACE, "host!192.168.78.252");
#endif
```

Comment: thanks, i tot windows is not supported. work like charm

Comment: Why curl Windows does not supprt specific "--interface"?